# Spring SpEL error

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

i'm new to Java, Spring and SpEL and i can't make this simple code work (it works without evaluation imports tho)

This is my Class RunSpring.java:

```
package run;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import helloworld.HelloSpringWorld;

public class RunSpring
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //App Context
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean-data.xml");
        BeanFactory beanFactory = appContext;
        HelloSpringWorld instance = (HelloSpringWorld);
        beanFactory.getBean("helloSpringWorld");

        //Expression to be evaluated
        instance.greeting("${5+5}");
    }
}
```

This is my class HelloSpringWorld:

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
//Expression imports
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;

@Service
public class HelloSpringWorld
{
    public void greeting(String name)
    {
        //Expression Setup
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(name);
        String message = (String) exp.getValue();

        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Spring: " + message);
    }
}
```

Error:  After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'

Any hints?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the `greeeting` method as follows.  Notice that `Integer.class` is passed to `getValue()`.

```
public void greeting(String name)
{
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(name);
    String message = exp.getValue(Integer.class).toString();

    System.out.println("Hello and welcome to Spring: " + message);
}
```

Then call with:

```
instance.greeting("5+5");
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `parser.parseExpression(name)` :)

Comment: @kocko Thanks for pointing that out.  It was left over from the test I made.